# How to run a script within an Amazon EC2 when the instance starts for the first time?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have made my own AMI's for internal purpose. How do I run a script when the instance is launched using this AMI? How can I do this?

My current approach is by adding the script, say myscript.sh, to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. Is this the right approach for AMIs?

Edit: Here is a scenario:

I have created an AMI (EC2 image) from an EC2 instance. Now when a colleague used this image and launchs an instance I want a script to be run only once when the instance is launched. I do not want this to run every time the instance is rebooted. Instead, only at the time of launching the instance for the first time.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125311/how-to-fire-ec2-instances-and-upload-run-a-startup-script-on-each-of-them

Comment: @LinuxDevOps, that's not what I want to do. Can you please check the edit I just made

Comment: @Ashwinkumar Can you explain why not?  User data executes on launch, not reboots.  It seems like it is exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Will check it out. Should the script be passed at the time of launching instance from the image file?? or is it just once when launching the instance and creating the image from the same instance?? :)

Comment: @HyperAnthony, I just tried it now. It does not work the way I want. When a new instance is  launched from the AMI the same script that was used while creating AMI does not work. :)

Comment: Stick it in rc.local as you're doing, but have the script delete itself when it finishes running.

Answer (score 6):

Provide your script via "user-data" during your launch process and it will be executed upon first boot. If you're using awscli, use the `--user-data` option"

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type m1.small --key-name foo-key --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxxx --placement AvailabilityZone=us-west-2a --user-data file://path/to/script
```

If you're using the GUI, the user data field is hidden in the "Advanced" section at the bottom of step 3 of the launch dialogue:
[image]

Comment: i guess my question was confusing or incomplete. have added an example. Can you share your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this? This topic describes how to add user data to a launch.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

This allows you to run a script once at launch, but you would have to specify the same user data each time you launch the AMI. Are you looking to have the same script run every time this AMI launches without ever having to enter it or the possibility of changing?

Comment: Exactly.. I am looking for a possibility to run the script everytime an instance is launched (only at launch, and should not at reboot) and I do not want to let the colleagues to pass the script via "User data".. For now I am doing it in a startup script and destroying after launching. That way it does not run again after a reboot of the instance